# Creating a new function in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I just installed CodeIgniter 2.1.4. I want to call several functions in a controller. I have the following code:

Controller galeria.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Galeria extends CI_Controller {


public function index() 
{
    $this->load->view('vgaleria');
}

public function tg() 
{
    $this->load->view('tgaleria');
}
}

?>
```

Views:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Galería de imágenes</title>

<style type="text/css">
</style>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>javascript/funciones.js"  
    language="javascript" input="type/text">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="imgs">
<img src="imagenes/imagen1.jpg" id="eimg">
</div>

<input type="button" id="bant" onclick="imgav('atras')" value="Anterior"></button>
<input type="button" id="bsig" onclick="imgav('adelante')" value="Siguiente"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

View tgaleria.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Galería de imágenes</title>

<style type="text/css">
</style>

<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>javascript/funciones.js"  
    language="javascript" input="type/text">

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="imgs">
<img src="imagenes/imagen1.jpg" id="eimg">
</div>

<input type="button" id="bant" onclick="imginter('arrancar')" value="Arrancar">   
</button>
<input type="button" id="bsig" onclick="imgparar()" value="Parar"></button>
```

The default controller is galeria.php.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "galeria";
```

When I type 
    http://example.com/codeigniter I have everything ok.

But when I type 
     http://example.com/codeigniter/tg.php 
I obtain the error 404, url not found.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just `http://example.com/codeigniter/tg` without the extension? Frameworks usually do some mod_rewrite magic for pretty URL's.

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Also there is a spell error in url.. its `codeigniter` not `codeingniter` :)

Comment: Have you used `.htaccess` to remove the `index.php`? if not then you must append it like `http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/galeria/tg` else `http://example.com/codeigniter/galeria/tg`

Comment: Yeah. Error of tipying. But this is not the problem. If I typed it correctly the error is not fixed.

Comment: I tried http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/galeria/tg and it works. The other one didn't work. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used `.htaccess` to remove the index.php? if not then you must append it like:

```
http://example.com/codeigniter/index.php/galeria/tg
```

else

```
http://example.com/codeigniter/galeria/tg
```

Here, `galeria` being your `Controller` and the `first segment` and `tg` your `function` and the `second segment` of the `URI`.